# Custom sorting in Infragistics

Tags: winforms, sorting, compare, infragistics

I would like to use custom sorting in Infgragistics.
I read that I can use IComparer.

I have an UltraGridColumnd Bound with string data type. I woule like to sort in by value from another column, which is long data type.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is possible and can be achieved exactly using IComparer interface. Each UltraGrid column has SortComparer property on which can be assigned object that implements IComparer interface. As written in the documentation about the SortComparer property:

> Property used to perform custom sort comparisons when sorting rows by
>   this column. The values passed in the Compare method of the IComparer
>   will be two UltraGridCell objects.

Here is code snippet regarding your scenario as the comparison values comes from another column.

```cs
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ultraGrid1.DataSource = InitializeDataSource(10);
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Override.HeaderClickAction = HeaderClickAction.SortMulti;
        ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns[0].SortComparer = new CustomComparer();
    }

    private DataTable InitializeDataSource(int rows)
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable();

        table.Columns.Add("String Column", typeof(string));
        table.Columns.Add("Long Column", typeof(long));

        for (int index = 0; index < rows; index++)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Text", index });
        }

        return table;
    }
}

public class CustomComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        var valueColumn = "Long Column";
        var firstCell = x as UltraGridCell;
        var secondCell = y as UltraGridCell;

        var firstCellValue = (long)firstCell.Row.Cells[valueColumn].Value;
        var secondCellValue = (long)secondCell.Row.Cells[valueColumn].Value;

        if (firstCellValue == secondCellValue)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (firstCellValue > secondCellValue)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```